# Nautilus broken in Linux, I cannot fix it by `apt-get`

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, apt-get, nautilus

As far as I know Nautilus is default file manager for GNOME.

Recently I updated it (this is what I think). What I did was:

```
apt-get install nautilus
```

After few minutes download was complete, after a restart when I tried to open Files it was not working. The file explorer will not open how hard I try.

Then I tried to remove it with the following command:

```
dpkg --list #(to confirm the file name)
apt-get remove nautilus/nautilus-data
```

But there was an error:

```
apt-get remove nautilus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.19.92) but 3.18.2-1 is to be installed
 libgnome-desktop-3-12 : Breaks: mutter (< 3.21.2) but 3.18.2-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Since I cannot remove it I have only one option i.e. to switch to some other file manager but I do not want to switch.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

EDIT(updated):
when I type nautilus in terminal it gives following error:

> nautilus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-autoar-0.so.0: undefined symbol: archive_entry_is_encrypted

I think maybe it is loading wrong libraries.
And I also tried

> apt-get install --reinstall nautilus

Error is still same

Comment: This may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel
Also, what does it say when you just enter `nautilus` in the terminal in your current state?

Comment: it gives error as follow: nautilus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-autoar-0.so.0: undefined symbol: archive_entry_is_encrypted

Comment: @sigalor i was already trying to remove it but the problem it while I try to remove it gives some error as posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe some solution to this,but I am only writing how I fixed it.
Run:

> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Due to any reason if process haults type:

> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade --fix-missing